# Moment of small balls in Riemannian manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be Riemannian manifold and $p_{1},p_{2}$ two points that we can suppose close enough to use normal coordinates.

My goal would be estimate the $1$-moment of the ball $B_{t}$ of center $p_{2}$ and radius $t$ at $p_{1}$, which is $$\int_{B_{t}}d(p_{1},x)d\mu$$

More precisely, ideally, I would like to get an aproximation of this moment depending on $d(p_{1},p_{2})$, the metric tensor at $p_{2}$ and some o$(t^{k})$.

My goal is to be able to compare this moment to $d(p_{1},p_{2})\times Vol(B_{t})$ when $d(p_{1},p_{2})$ is small and $t$ is small compared to $d(p_{1},p_{2})$.

EDIT : I will share some incomplete reasonning that might be improved to get to a solution.

We know that we can define the sectional curvature at a point $x$ and two unit tangent vectors $v,w$ as the quantity $K(v,w)$ such that we have:

$$d(\exp_{x}\epsilon w,\exp_{\exp_{x}\delta v}(\epsilon w+\delta v))=\delta(1-\epsilon^{2}\frac{1}{2}K(v,w))+O(\delta\epsilon^{3}+\delta^{2}\epsilon^{2})$$
where $\epsilon,\delta$ are small reals and $\epsilon w+\delta v$ denote the parrallel transport of $\epsilon w$ along $\delta v$.

[[image: here <span class=]$\exp_{x}\delta v$ is denoted $y$ and $\epsilon w,\epsilon w+\delta v$ are denoted $w_{x}$ and $w_{y}$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCvlB.png)

Let us work under the (optimistic and unclear) assumption that there exists a constant $A$ such that the sectional curvature also check:
$$d(\exp_{x}\epsilon w,\exp_{x}\delta v)=|\delta v-\epsilon w|(1-\epsilon^{2}AK(v,w))+O(\text{smaller expression of $\epsilon,\delta\to 0$})$$

Coming back to our case, here $x$ would be the center $p$ of the small ball $B(p,r)$, $\delta v$ would be the antecedant of $q$ by the exponentiel at $p$ and $\exp_{x}\epsilon w=\exp_{p}\epsilon w$ would vary inside the ball $B(p,r)$

Therefore, the moment at $q$ end up as:
$$\int_{u\in B_{r}}|\delta v-u|(1-\epsilon^{2}AK(v,\frac{u}{|u|}))+(\text{small terms in $\delta,r\to 0$})$$

were $B_{r}$ denote the euclidian ball of radius $r$ at the origin.

Denote
$$E=\int_{u\in B_{r}}|\delta v-u|$$
$E$ is the euclidian case of the problem.

Then the 1-moment $M$ of $B(p,r)$ at $q$ become:
$$M=E-\int_{u\in B_{r}}|\delta v-u|\epsilon^{2}AK(v,\frac{u}{|u|})+(\text{small terms in $\delta,r\to 0$})$$

Now if we denote $R=\int_{u\in B_{r}}|\delta v-u|\epsilon^{2}AK(v,\frac{u}{|u|})$ so that:
$$M=E-R+\text{(smaller terms in $\delta,r\to 0$)}$$
under which hypothesis can I obtain a control of $R$ in $\delta,r$ relatively to $E$, for example, is there hypothesis on $Ricc_{x}(v)$ that allow to put $R$ in the "smaller term in $\delta,r\to 0$" ?

And also, am I too bold to assume the existence of the constant $A$ ?

Comment: What kind of approximation do you want? Do you want a power series expansion? See https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-20/issue-4/The-volume-of-a-small-geodesic-ball-of-a-Riemannian/10.1307/mmj/1029001150.full. To get an upper bound, you can write the integral as $$ \int_{r=0}^{r=t} r A(S(p,r))\,dr, $$ where $S(p,r)$ is the boundary of the geodesic ball $B(p,r)$ of radius $r$, centered at $p$, and $A$ denotes $(n-1)$-dimensional volume and use the Bishop-Gromov inequality (e.g., see https://web.math.ucsb.edu/~wei/paper/Wei2012survey.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the insight
The integral you wrote would be the moment of $B(p,r)$ at $p$, however I'm trying to estimate it at some other point $q$, therefore you don't have constant function $r$ on each sphere $S(p,r)$.

Are the power series developpement still able to give an insight in this case ?

Comment: I edited the initial to include a line of reasoning I tried